# Azure alert: The portal is having issues getting authentication tokens for Microsoft_Azure_Compute, SqlAzureExtension

Tags: azure, azureportal

I'm getting this alert but I can't seem to find any information related to it online.  I seem to be getting it 4 times every 6 hours.  I have a SQL database up and running with Microsoft's test AdventureWorks db on it, and 5 test VMs that are all deallocated.  Anyone had this and solved it, or know where to guide me to get this resolved?

Only other thing I can find is this, which doesn't seem to apply, as I have no web apps or services installed: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f2a8b549-3be7-413e-a233-cf66acf9fd8b/portal-is-having-issues-getting-authentication-token-in-azure?forum=windowsazuremanagement

Answer (score 0):

App Service Authentication/Authorization is exposed in the Azure Preview Management Portal. To enable it, navigate the **Settings** blade of **any Web or Mobile App** and select **Authentication/Authorization**. Flip the **switch to On** to view the options for protecting your site.

For more information, kindly refer the link given below:
[click here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-user-principal-auth/)

Hope this helps.